# CSS Grid 50% Divided Width Cell With Background Image Does not fit Screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use css grid to make 2x2 rectangles with equal width(dividing screen into 2) but for some reason right side ones are expanding pages width and creates scrollbar.

[not fiting to screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwwo3.png)

CSS:

```
.indexGridContainer{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: minmax(250px, 450px);

}
.wallets{

    position:relative;
    background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/686/bellroy-brand-homepage-2.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
.bags{
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/691/bellroy-brand-homepage-7.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .keys{
        position:relative;
        background-image: url( https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/688/bellroy-brand-homepage-4.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .phonecases{
        position:relative;
        background-image: url( https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/690/bellroy-brand-homepage-6.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
.titleBox{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.titleBox h1{
    font-family: 'PT serif', 'serif';
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
.titleBox h3{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="indexGridContainer">
<a  href="#" class="wallets">
<span class="titleBox">
<h1>Men's Wallets</h1>
<h3>>SLIM YOUR WALLET</h3>


</span>

</a>
<a  href="#" class="keys">
<span class="titleBox">
<h1>Key Covers</h1>
<h3>>STOP THE JANGLE</h3>


</span>

</a>
<a  href="#" class="bags">
<span class="titleBox">
<h1>Bags</h1>
<h3>>Merge work and Play into one</h3>


</span>

</a>
<a  href="#" class="phonecases">
<span class="titleBox">
<h1>Phone Cases</h1>
<h3>>Streamline your phone and wallet.</h3>


</span>

</a>


</div>
```

codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOXooP

Is there a problem with .indexGridContainer ? is repeat(2,1fr); is wrong way to divide screens width 50%  ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `.titlebox` has a property of `left: 20px`, causing white space on the right when its width is 50% of the page's. Reduce its width, or if you're lazy, add the following CSS to work around the issue:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using span as a container of block elements which is not correct. You need to use div instead and consider margin to create space and not adjust the position because you will simply create an overflow on the right if you push the element from the left.

Also don't forget to remove default body margin if you want to cover all the screen:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}

.indexGridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(250px, 450px);
}
.indexGridContainer > a {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wallets {
  background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/686/bellroy-brand-homepage-2.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
}

.bags {
  background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/691/bellroy-brand-homepage-7.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
}

.keys {
  background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/688/bellroy-brand-homepage-4.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
}

.phonecases {
  background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/690/bellroy-brand-homepage-6.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
}

.titleBox {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.titleBox h1 {
  font-family: 'PT serif', 'serif';
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.titleBox h3 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="indexGridContainer">
  <a href="#" class="wallets">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <h1>Men's Wallets</h1>
      <h3>>SLIM YOUR WALLET</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="keys">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <h1>Key Covers</h1>
      <h3>>STOP THE JANGLE</h3>
    </div>

  </a>
  <a href="#" class="bags">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <h1>Bags</h1>
      <h3>>Merge work and Play into one</h3>
    </div>

  </a>
  <a href="#" class="phonecases">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <h1>Phone Cases</h1>
      <h3>>Streamline your phone and wallet.</h3>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```